# How to fix protonvpn TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_dir_path'?

Tags: python, arch

I am using linux (Manjaro kde plasma).

When trying to run protonvpn from the task manager, it fails to start and does not give any errors, When run using the command line it outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/protonvpn_gui/main.py", line 262, in do_activate
    if not protonvpn.check_session_exists():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/api.py", line 344, in check_session_exists
    return self._env.api_session.is_valid
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/environment.py", line 55, in api_session
    self.__api_session = APISession()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/session/session.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.__session_create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/session/session.py", line 232, in __session_create
    self.__proton_api = Session(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_dir_path'
```

I have tried restarting and rebuilding which has not changed anything.

Comment: where did you get `protonvpn`? Maybe this program needs older Python version.

Comment: @furas i got `protonvpn` from the `aur` by following the [instructions given on the protonvpn website](https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-client-arch/)

Comment: I tested it only with `Linux Mint` and `Python 3.8` and it works for me. `Python 3.9` needed some change in source code because there was mistake in some place - but it was different problem. Maybe it has some mistake also in your code and it need changes. You could send this problem to [ProtonVPN Support](https://protonvpn.com/support/)

Comment: I digged in source code and it seems `Session` is in module `proton-client` - so maybe it needs to update this module [proton-client](https://pypi.org/project/proton-client/)

Comment: @furas `proton-client` is already up to date so this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Even though this seems to be a bug, I think you just want to use that software, otherwise you'd e.g. provide a [mcve]. So, check bug reports and report your own when this error is new.

Comment: error shows problem with `Session()` which is imported from `proton.api` (I checked it in source code). So all problem is with `proton`. Maybe you have two Pythons and updated this module for different Python. Error shows you full path to file in which you get problem - so you can open it in text editor and modify and remove `log_dir_path` maybe it will resolve this problem

Comment: @furas removing `log_dir_path` ,`cache_dir_path` and `tls_pinning` allows me to open the application but it remains unusable as a `unknown error` still occurs

Comment: it is strange that you have problem with `log_dir_path`, etc. First you could check `proton` version `import proton` and `print( proton.constants.VERSION )` I have `0.7.1`. You can also see this number in [proton/constants.py](https://github.com/ProtonMail/proton-python-client/blob/master/proton/constants.py). In source code of [Session](https://github.com/ProtonMail/proton-python-client/blob/master/proton/api.py#L114) you can also see that it can get `log_dir_path`, etc.

Comment: source code for 0.5.1 - [Session](https://github.com/ProtonMail/proton-python-client/blob/0.5.1/proton/api.py#L51) - shows that it doesn't have `log_dir_path`, etc.  - so it can means you use older `proton-client`. So you should try again install newest proton using `python3.9 -m pip install -U proton-client`

Comment: @furas Same output even after running `python3.9 -m pip install -U proton-client`

Comment: it is strange. It behave like you would have two `python 3.9` installed and you install `proton-client` in one Python and it runs code with different Python. Maybe you have to install modules with `sudo` - to install it for all users.

Comment: @furas it may be that. I can't currently test it to see if it will work however I will comment the results when I can

Comment: @furas i have tried installing `protonvpn` using  `sudo pamac build protonvpn` however i still get the same error

Comment: @furas i decided to delete protonvpn then update everything that needed a update using the `add/remove software` and then installing `protonvpn` again and it has seemed to fix my issue. thank you for your help

Comment: you could put it as answer - maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to delete `protonvpn` then update everything that needed an update using the `add/remove software` and then installing `protonvpn` again and it has seemed to fix my issue. Sorry if this is an uninformative answer.

edit: checking the `pacman` log shows that many python related packages were upgraded.